# How can i make this Linq Statement more sophisticated

Tags: linq, linq-to-entities

After many hours of research i still can't get this query to shorten, but surely there is a way... My current query looks like so

```
decimal Cost = db.U_MBP
    .Where(w => w.Model == ModelNumber)
    .Select(s => s.Cost ?? 0)
    .FirstOrDefault();
double Margin = db.U_MBP
    .Where(w => w.Model == ModelNumber)
    .Select(s => s.Margin ?? 0)
    .FirstOrDefault();
decimal BasePrice = Cost / (decimal)Margin;
```

What I was initially trying to accomplish was an all in 1 linq statement, something like

```
decimal BasePrice = db.U_MBP
    .Where(w => w.Model == ModelNumber)
    .Select(s => s.Cost ?? 0 / (decimal)s.Margin ?? 0)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

But i cannot get over the cast error.

**Casting to Decimal is not supported in LINQ to Entities queries, because the required precision and scale information cannot be inferred.**

Can any of you help?

Answer with D's Help

```
decimal BasePrice = (decimal)(db.Utilities_ModelsBasePrices
                .Where(w => w.Model == ModelNumber)
                .Select(s => (s.Margin == null || s.Margin == 0) ? (double)0m :
                                    ((double)s.Cost) / (double)s.Margin)
                .FirstOrDefault());
```

Comment: Can you please post the exact error you are getting? Also, `(decimal)s.Margin ?? 0` is a divide by zero error waiting to happen...

Comment: don't you need to group `??` in parentheses for proper associativity in your last code snippet?

Comment: @AbeMiessler yeah i'm just trying to get it to work first though, **ERROR: Casting to Decimal is not supported in LINQ to Entities queries, because the required precision and scale information cannot be inferred.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
.Select(s => s.Cost ?? 0 / (decimal)s.Margin ?? 0)
```

The `??` operator has lower precedence than the `/` operator, so it's effectively calculating:

```
.Select(s => s.Cost ?? (0 / (decimal)s.Margin) ?? 0)
```

which translates to

```
if (s.Cost == null)
   if((0 / (decimal)s.Margin))== null
       return 0;
   else
       return (0 / (decimal)s.Margin);      
else
    return s.Cost;
```

You need to add parens when using `??` and other operators:

```
decimal BasePrice = db.U_MBP
    .Where(w => w.Model == ModelNumber)
    .Select(s => (s.Cost ?? 0) / ((decimal)s.Margin ?? 0))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

However, you will get a divide-by-zero exception if s.Margin is `null` or 0.  I would recommend:

```
decimal BasePrice = (decimal)(db.U_MBP
    .Where(w => w.Model == ModelNumber)
    .Select(s => (s.Margin == null || s.Margin == 0) ? 0.0 :
                      ((double)s.Cost ?? 0) / s.Margin)
    .FirstOrDefault());
```

Eric Lippert [recently posted](https://communities.coverity.com/blogs/development-testing-blog/2013/10/23/oct-23-post-c--static-values) about the null coalescing precedence on his blog.

Comment: Error on the last query you have in your answer: Casting to Decimal is not supported in LINQ to Entities queries, because the required precision and scale information cannot be inferred.

Comment: I've amended it to do the math as a double then cast to a decimal.

Comment: Thanks so much i had to tweak it minorly to get it to work :) ill edit my post, thanks so much!!